# onCloseDialog doesn't close the Dialog

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have Dialog which is in fragment. There I have:

```
<Button text="{i18n>buttonClose}" press="onCloseDialog"/>
```

and in controller there is:

```
openDialog: function () {
      if (!this.pressDialog1) {
        this.pressDialog1 = sap.ui.xmlfragment("mypackage.fragment.Dialog", this);
      }
      this.pressDialog1.open();
    },
    onCloseDialog: function () {
      this.pressDialog1.close();
    },
```

when I debug it in console it goes into `openDialog` function but when I try to close it doesn't go into `onCloseDialog`. I have also noticed that there is a warning in console:

```
event handler function "onCloseDialog" is not a function or does not exist in the controller.
```

Why it doesn't go into `onCloseDialog` function?

@Edit
openDialog is called like:

```
var controllerName = "mypackage.ProdE"
sap.ui.controller(controllerName, {

  openDialog: function () {
        if (!this.pressDialog1) {
          this.pressDialog1 = sap.ui.xmlfragment("mypackage.fragment.Dialog", this)
          this.getView().addDependent(this.pressDialog1);
        }
        this.pressDialog1.open();
      },
    onCloseDialog: function () {
      this.pressDialog1.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is pretty simple, your Dialog is not attached to your controller so it's not executing the onCloseDialog method you have implemented.

This is the correct way to handle dialog:

```
onOpenDialog: function(oEvent) {
    if ( !this._oDialog ) {
        this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "mypackage.fragment.Dialog", this);

        // This is important becuase your dialog will be attached to the view lifecycle
        this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
    }

    this._oDialog.open();
},

ondialogClose: function(oEvent) {
    // Do cleaning stuff
    this._oDialog.close();
}
```